# React application from github not running on VS Code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

sorry for newbie question. I have downloaded a react application from github. When I try to run locally on VS Code it gives me some dependencies errors.
Below is the dependencies on the json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.5",
"@emotion/react": "^11",
"@emotion/styled": "^11",
"@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.8",
"algoliasearch": "^4.12.1",
"axios": "^0.26.0",
"framer-motion": "^6",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-hook-form": "^7.27.1",
"react-icons": "^4.3.1",
"react-images-uploading": "^3.1.3",
"react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.22.0",
"react-query": "^3.34.16",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
"react-table": "^7.7.0",
"recharts": "^2.1.9",
"sass": "^1.49.9",
"yup": "^0.32.11",
"zustand": "^3.7.0"
```

}

Error:

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: admin-family@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-images-uploading@3.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-images-uploading
npm ERR!   react-images-uploading@"^3.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\12392\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\12392\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-09T00_59_26_007Z-debug-0.log
```

Running node v16.14.0
Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: Can you share repo link?

Comment: [react-images-uploading](https://github.com/vutoan266/react-images-uploading) v3.1.3 requires a peer dependency of React v16.8 but you have React v17. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/vutoan266/react-images-uploading/issues/107) for updates or downgrade React

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

this will fix the error, because it ignores the peer dependencies and focuses on the main dependencies.

this has worked for me whenever i've gotten this error